# Show installer UI when repairing program

Tags: windows-installer, custom-action

I have a Visual Studio Installer (VS 2010) project with a custom action to verify that the user has entered a value into one of the UI textboxes during installation. If the value is not present, it displays an error message and stops the installation. This all works fine.

The problem arises when the user goes into Programs and Features and tries to repair the application. They see the error requiring the value and are unable to proceed. What I think I'd like to do is display the UI when repairing and give the user a chance to enter the value. Is this possible? Is there another way to get them through the repair process successfully?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cause the Repair button in [Programs and Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368032) to show more than [basic UI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372096). You can set the property [`ARPNOREPAIR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367592) to 1 in order to hide the button, which would require the user to either enter maintenance (typically through a Modify or Change button) to perform such an operation from Programs and Features. However auto-repair would still use basic UI, and the user could invoke anything from the command line with the proper arguments to msiexec.

While you can document your way around most of the problems with the latter (just tell them what property to set with your value), auto-repair is hard to suppress. So either you have to detect auto-repair and modify your approach only then (I have vague memories of [`REINSTALLMODE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371182) including a `p` which is rarely suggested elsewhere), or modify your general approach to not require this value be entered during maintenance.

Without knowing more about what this value is or what it is intended for, I would tentatively suggest the last approach because it's simple and idiomatic. Accept and store this value in the registry during first-time installation, and read it from the registry during maintenance operations. Optionally let them enter (override) it if they're running maintenance in full UI or from the command line. If this is a configuration property, this is almost definitely the right move. If it is more of a "password", it's questionable, but I'd argue you should trust Windows's protections around administrative access more than any password scheme you can implement inside an MSI.

Whatever else you do, don't forget to handle the basic and silent UI cases. For first time install, in particular, it's best to either have a default fallback for the value, or to explicitly check for it, log a verbose message so the user can determine what's going on, and abort the installation. The same approach should work for other invocations if the value is actually required then. Just be careful about aborting when the program is already installed; broken auto-repair or uninstallation are both awful experiences.